# Prevent JSON4S from skipping JSON objects with a missing field

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Let's suppose I have a simple JSON array like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    "name": "Alex",
    "age": 12
  },
  { 
    "name": "Peter"
  }
]
```

Notice that the second object doesn't have an `age` field.

I'm using JSON4S to query JSON (using the `for-comprehension` style to extract values):

```
 for {
      JArray(persons) <- json
      JObject(person) <- persons
      JField("name", JString(name)) <- person
      JField("age", JString(age)) <- person
 } yield new Person(name, age)
```

The problem for me is that this expression will skip the second object (the one with the missing `age` field). I don't want to skip such objects; I need to get it as `null` or better as `None`.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32453990/921193) gives an example of how to deal with `null` values in JSON using custom extractors, but it works only if the field is present and if its value is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deconstructing objects in json4s may lead to some inconvenience, as you no longer can use fancy `\` and `\\` queries.

I prefer to do something like that:

```
for {
    JArray(persons) <- json
    person@JObject(_) <- persons
    JString(name) <- person \ "name"
    age = (person \ "age").extractOpt[Int]
     } yield (name, age)

res7: List[(String, Option[Int])] = List(("Alex", Some(12)), ("Peter", None))
```

This example also illustrates two alternatives how object fields can be extracted (you can also use `name =  (person \ "name").extract[String]` instead).